# A question about the proper usage of articles

Tags: articles

I am working on my paper in English. It concerns the so-called problem of perception. The concept of the problem of perception is part of epistemological literature about perception; some argue that as long as we have illusions, hallucinations etc. our ordinary conception of perception is false. I am trying to show that the argument is incorrect itself. Since perception itself, as a phenomenon, does not 'suffer' from any such problem but, as I argue, the mentioned argument does, I think it would be useful to emphasize this in the title. This seems due for against the background of the 'infallibility' of perception itself the falsity of the argument will become more salient. So far I have had this version as a working one:

Is the "Problem of Perception" a Problem of Perception?

As I understand, article "the" supports there the meaning of a specific epistemological problem the reader is familiar with, and article "a" that of one problem of the possible many of perception itself. Yet am not sure that the articles actually support the meaning I would like to express by the title. So here is my question:

Does the above combination of articles, 'the' and 'a', respectively support the intended meaning?

Comment: The title would be correct with lower case articles "a" and "the."  However, I don't care for it; I don't think it conveys very well the concept you explained.

Comment: My question was not supposed to be considered on the matter of its theoretical soundness but with respect to its grammatical aspect. I clearly stated that the question is about the proper usage of articles--whether the articles support the intended meaning or not. The obvious answer here is either yes or no rather than 'it is primarily opinion-based'. The latter just conflates the two aspects, confusion.

Comment: By this I would like to elaborate on my previous comment. The idea in question is that the concept of the Problem of Perception as is (in epistemological literature) is due to erroneous ways of thinking about perception. This is not 'a matter of opinion' but a matter of research. Again my question was whether the articles sequence support that idea in the working title. Here an obvious answer is yes or no, not 'a matter of opinion'.

Comment: The question could also be closed as seeking proofreading.

Comment: perhaps, but it is closed for other not this reason, which is fact. sadly,  my current experience here is that people entitled to close a question do not bother to follow the meaning of what is asked.

Comment: Giorgi, you can pre-post a question in Meta and ask for assistance editing the question to fit the customs of the site.

Comment: The most basic fix of the proposed title would be "Is the 'Problem of Perception' Really a Problem of Perception?" but I still think it could be improved.  At any rate, that would fix the obvious mechanical problems.

Comment: Your comments help. I thought about this version too. Could you clarify what you meant by the mechanical problems? Actually, this is just a working title. My main interest was when publishing this if the sequence of the articles has actually supported the explained meaning. I was/am primarily interested in how the articles work there.

Comment: The question is fine, clear, and answerable. I agree with Aparente that the articles are used properly and as intended.

Comment: Mechanical problems: basic grammar and usage.

Comment: @tchrist As a matter of fact: the question was put on hold and then closed under the category, primarily oppinion based, not the current one.

Comment: "Proper" according to who exactly?

Comment: "Proper" involves the meaning of the norm--namely, that there are norms you must follow if you want to communicate with others, as well as with yourself, in this language rather than something else. Therefore, "proper" according to the norms that exclusively make it possible for the reader and the author, in this case, to communicate on the same subject matter in a specific language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the articles are used correctly for your context. You might want to consider keeping *the* outside the quitation marks.